# Kendo-Knockout: Calling a method that changes viewmodel property from a template with data-binding inside a grid, breaks bindings

Tags: knockout.js, kendo-ui

I am using RPNiemeyer`s kendo-knockout library. I have a kendo grid with a kendo template in it. In the template there is a button which uses knockout click binding which calls a method that changes the viewModel. Steps to reproduce:

1. Click the button in the grid.
2. A method is called that changes the property of the viewModel and alerts the new value.
3. Click the button again. The button is not working any more.

Note: If You remove the line that changes the property of the viewmodel everything is working fine.

Please explain the reason why this is not working and any ideas and solutions will be greatly appreciated. Thank You!

html:

```
<div id="grid"  data-bind="kendoGrid: { data: fruits, columns: [ 
            {
                field: 'name',
                title: 'Fruit',
                width: 50
            },
            {
                template: '<button class=\'k-button\' data-bind=\'click: function() { changeFruit() }\' >Change Fruit Name</button>',
                width: 30
            }               

         ], 
        scrollable: false, sortable: true, pageable: false }" style="height: 380px">
    </div>
```

javascript:

```
var ViewModel = function() {
    this.fruit1 = {
        color: ko.observable("green"),
        name: ko.observable("apple"),
    };

    this.fruit2 = {
        color: ko.observable("orange"),
        name: ko.observable("orange"),
    };


    this.fruits = ko.observableArray([
        this.fruit1, 
        this.fruit2
    ]);

    this.changeFruit = function() {
        // this line breaks the binding, 
        // when You change the property of the viewModel
        // You cannot call this function any more
        this.fruits()[0].name("Test");
        alert(this.fruits()[0].name());
    }
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hXn7e/25/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Knockout templates inside of the grid is not fully supported at this point.  Right now your row is bound, because the elements are there when Knockout first passes over the document to apply bindings.

After the data is updated, the rows are re-rendered and the bindings are lost.

One fix is to use an event handler for the "dataBound" event that rebinds the table.  This could be done globally, something like:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.kendoGrid.options.dataBound = function(data) {
    var body = this.element.find("tbody")[0];

    if (body) {
       ko.applyBindings(ko.dataFor(body), body);   
    }
};
```

Here is a sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/5Zkyg/

I also added a custom binding that prevents Knockout from binding the table on the first pass, so that it is not bound twice (once overall applyBindings and once from the dataBound handler.

Ultimately, this is something that I want to support better in Knockout-Kendo and it is the next thing that I plan to work on with the library.

Here is a sample of how it might work from a branch that I had started a while back: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/xBL2B/

Comment: Thank You very much. Looking forward to see this implementation in the main branch.

Comment: This code is executed twice on loading the page: ko.applyBindings(ko.dataFor(body), body); Can You explain why? Updated fiddle with alert on the binding: http://jsfiddle.net/5Zkyg/17/

Comment: The first time the grid is actually empty, so the binding doesn't do anything.  The second time is actually when the data has been set.  So, in this case it is harmless.  Hoping to work on the data-bound templates very soon.

Comment: Hmm my button handler is being called twice. That is until I press one of the paging buttons on the Kendo Grid. Any Ideas?

Comment: Maybe you have a jsFiddle?

Comment: Sure. One other thing I noticed is the click handler isn't getting the correct data passed to it. It's getting the global viewModel instead of the row clicked. http://jsfiddle.net/CraigHead/zAFSX/

Comment: BTW, I also tried using KO Templates but I kept getting errors about properties not existing. Sooooo.. I'm stuck between a rock and a hard place atm.

Comment: To prevent the double binding, you need to add the `stopBindings` binding on the element that your grid binding is on.  This prevents it from binding the children inadvertently. To get the actual row item, it is not as clean as would be nice, but here is one solution: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/maBk9/. Note that the item passed is a clean copy used by the grid.

Comment: Hey that's really cool! Now I understand what the "widget" parameter does. Thanks for that little bit.