# Kendo-Knockout: Calling a method that changes viewmodel property from a template with data-binding inside a grid (Updated to knockout 2.3.0)

Tags: knockout.js, kendo-ui

I am using RPNiemeyer`s kendo-knockout library, and trying to use a databinding inside a template in kendoGrid. Previously [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13858087) question had the solution with refreshing bindings, but after I updated to knockout.js 2.3.0, this solution no longer works. knockout.js is now throwing an exception when executing ko.applyBindings multiple times for the same element.

I've also tried implementing it with knockout templates and useKOTemplates, but then sorting the grid by clicking column headers no longer works.

Any ideas how to solve this, or do I have do use kendo MVVM for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this particular scenario you should be able to add a `ko.cleanNode` call in the `dataBound` callback.  Something like:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.kendoGrid.options.dataBound = function(data) {
    var body = this.element.find("tbody")[0];

    if (body) {
       ko.cleanNode(body);
       ko.applyBindings(ko.dataFor(body), body);   
    }
};
```

Comment: This worked great. Thank you!

I have a little consern though, that this method with reapplying bindings is not very performant. I'm polling for data every 15 seconds or so. The amount of data is not that big. What do you think?

Comment: This technique is not ideal (I hope to improve it at some point in the library), but in your scenario it doesn't sound like a problem.  The content gets swapped out and then rebound.  The `cleanNode` is used because the root node remains.

Comment: Turns out that this solution causes a memory leak, as ko.cleanNode doesn't remove event listeners. See [link](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/910).