# Reapplying Knockout Bindings for Kendo Grid on paging

Tags: knockout.js, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Currently having a problem with my Kendo grid's pagination/filtering. My grid is pretty standard, 6 columns, 4 that literally just spit out data from the model and 2 that display data from the model but have a Kendo tooltip applied with knockout bindings. The problem I'm having is specifically with the tooltip MVVM bindings. They work great with the first page of data but when you go to the second page, or filter the grid, the tooltips don't appear.

I've narrowed down the problem there, its that the new html for the new rows doesn't exist when the bindings are applied to the page. Simple problem of reapplying the bindings to the new html right? Wrong. Thats the solution I'm sure but I can't figure out how to accomplish it as its Kendo that is generating the new HTML and I can't figure out a way to intercept it and grab the new html to reapply the bindings to.

I'm assuming the solution would involve something like this:

```
self.interceptPaging = function(e) {
    var newElements = e.sender.content;
    ko.applyBindingsToNode(newElements[0], null, viewModel);
}
```

But where do I get the new elements from? As is, e.sender.content throws an error about binding the grid twice. Suggestions welcome!

See my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Icestorm0141/oe3nrk8f/1/) for a working example of my problem.

**UPDATE:**

As jsFiddle seems to be having problems working with knockout 3.2, I plugged this into Telerik's dojo: [Here](http://dojo.telerik.com/Ikil)

**UPDATE #2: SOLUTION**

Found the solution. On top of the databound function above, I had to add a custom binding handler to disable descendant bindings.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.allowBindings = {
    init: function (elem, valueAccessor) {
        // Let bindings proceed as normal *only if* my value is false
        var shouldAllowBindings = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
        return { controlsDescendantBindings: !shouldAllowBindings };
    }
};
```

I added this attribute to the kendo grid div.

```
<div data-role="grid"
     data-bind="kendoGrid: gridOptions, allowBindings: false "
     style="height: 500px">
</div>
```

I also had to make a call to ko.cleanNode before the applyBindings call above. So my databound function looks like:

```
self.dataBound = function (e){
    var body = e.sender.element.find("tbody")[0];

    if (body) {
        ko.cleanNode(body);
        ko.applyBindings(ko.dataFor(body), body);
    }        
};
```

See updated [Telerik Dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/Ikil/2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are absolutely right. Kendo introduces new elements onto the page and knockout has no clue that it needs to apply bindings.

You can leverage the dataBound event for this:

```
dataBound: function(){
     var body = this.element.find("tbody")[0];

     if (body) {
        ko.applyBindings(ko.dataFor(body), body);   
     }}
}
```

I've updated your fiddle below.

http://jsfiddle.net/oe3nrk8f/2/

Also, take a look at this question to see how you could modify the source of the kendo-knockout library to do this for you automatically, but that might be overkill.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13863191/4316646

Comment: This works really great in jsfiddle with version 2.2 of knockout but when I pull it into my application, which runs version 3.2 of knockout, I get a "cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same  element" error. I plugged in 2.2 for knockout because 3.2 was giving me problems in fiddle. I had to go to the Telerik dojo to get an example of what I'm facing with knockout 3.2. http://dojo.telerik.com/Ikil

Any suggestions? Been trying to figure this one out all day.

Comment: Found the solution. On top of the databound function above, I had to add a custom binding handler to disable descendant bindings. I added this attribute to the kendo grid div. I also had to make a call to ko.cleanNode before the applyBindings call above. See updated Telerik Dojo. http://dojo.telerik.com/Ikil/2

Comment: This is really good to know. Thanks for the update and glad you sorted it out.

Comment: Ya from looking into it the problem, it looks like knockout 2.0 returns null if an item is bound twice. In version 2.3 they updated this to throw an error as you should never bind twice. However, in this case the grid is being bound once with kendo, and the second time is with knockout. So two bindings, but two separate types.